# What's the best way to find the shortest array in a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

Say for example I have an array that looks like this:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2]];
```

I'm trying to find the first shortest array inside `myArray` which in this case would be `myArray[2]`.

Obviously I could just write a loop, checking the length of each array and returning the smallest one. What I'm wondering is if there's a really clean or cleaver way to do it in javascript. Something along the lines of this: http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

Thanks!

Comment: You always will have to loop unless the outer array is sorted or something. Resig's implementation is not really faster (in terms of complexity), it only has shorter code than an explicit loop.

Comment: No.  But you can use companion hash tables and arrays to index and record size and order when you update it.  Create a class that behaves like a list but implements a method that returns the most empty container.  You can update this value when pushing something onto a container or popping something off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you could do it like this:

```
var shortest = myArray.reduce(function(p,c) {return p.length>c.length?c:p;},{length:Infinity});
```

This uses an internal loop so it's faster than manually running your own loop, but would require a shim to work in older browsers.

Comment: What's the `i==0` thing good for? You didn't pass an init argument anyway.

Comment: What's the shim needed for? The reduce function? What exactly does 'old browsers' mean?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question: Array.reduce doesn't work in any IE earlier than 9, FireFox earlier than 3, and Safari earlier than 4.

Comment: @Bergi Since you're looking for the shortest, the init argument would have to be an array such that `arr.length === Infinity`. Obviously, this is not possible, so some trickery is required to emulate that first step.

Comment: @Kolink: But you still have to pass in some init argument if you explicitly want to skip it. JavaScript's `fold` works like a `fold1` if no init argument is supplied, so you are actually skipping `myArray[0]`. So remove tha `i==0||`, and optionally pass `{length:-Infinity}` (it would make a difference if `myArray` was empty)

Comment: ... right, totally forgot I could just pass in an object with a length property on infinity XD Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are looking for using max or min looks like this.

```
Math.max.apply(Math, $.map(array, function (index) { return index.length }));
```

The trick is mapping to the inner arrays length attribute.

Comment: And how do you get the value of the shortest one ?

Comment: @Vatev: `array.filter(function(a){return a.length==maxlength;})` :-)

Comment: yea, this is as far as I got trying to implement Resig's example.

Answer (score 0):

If by best you mean fastest time.. You will not achive a solution that is better than O(N), since you must check each element in the array (assuming it is unsorted).

Since you cannot achieve anything better than O(N), I see no reason not to do something like the following:

```
var myArray = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2]];

var shortestIndex = 0;

for( var i=1; i< myArray.length; i++){
    if(myArray[shortestIndex].length > myArray[i].length)
        shortestIndex = i;
}
```

now `myArray[shortestIndex]` is the shortest array.

Comment: Using a variable `shortestArray` would me much more readable to me.

Comment: "Since you cannot achieve anything better than O(N)..." Sure, not any better in terms of complexity but one O(N) might still be 1000 times slower than another O(N). I'm not sure that would be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript array `reduce`. Remember that a reducer will only return one value, we will be reducing the array into a value.

```
   reduce(callback,initialValue)
```

JavaScript invokes the callback function upon each item of the array

```
const findShortestArray = (arr = []) => {
  //  we iterate over array and "val" is the current array element that we are on
  // acc is the current result so far
  const res = arr.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
    if (!index || val.length < acc[0].length) {
      return [val];
    }
    if (val.length === acc[0].length) {
      acc.push(val);
    }
    return acc;
  // initial value=[]
  }, []);
  return res;
};
```